# Почему утилита arping не обучает arp таблицу?

Tags: linux, ip, ping, arp

На системе Ubuntu 20.0 делаю arping хоста по ip из подсети, получаю ответ, но при этом arp таблица не обучается! То есть ни в выводе утилиты ARP ни в файле /proc/net/arp нету нужной записи, хотя первый arp-запрос улетает широковещательно, а последующие уже unicast'ом. Объясните пожалуйста почему так ??

p.s если сделать обычный ping нужного хоста, то arp таблица обновится.

Comment: arp таблица ведется ядром, так как ядро само arp-запрос не отправляло то и ответ оно обрабатывать не будет (во избежание arp poison атак). А тут запрос создает не ядро, а сама утилита arping и ядро об этом не знает. И на unicast arping переходит по своим данным, а не по наличию записей в arp таблице

Comment: зачем арпингу уникаст?